# Spiked text in SKLabelNode

Tags: ios, xcode, fonts, sklabelnode

Spiked text in SKLabelNode, font exist in project. When add text in SKLabel node I see many artefacts on font like this : 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nZkAu.png)

this screen shot from iPhone 6s. I think this is SpriteKit work, but hove fix this?

Answer (score 0):

I found solution - 1) you myst divide SKLabel font on 2;  2) you must scale up you SKLabelNode by 2

[pWinningsLabel setFontSize:25 * self.size.width / 1024 /2];

```
pWinningsLabel.xScale = 2.0f;
pWinningsLabel.yScale = 2.0f;
```